# cannot insert the desired data to wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

the inserted data always result to Upland even though I selected either the tab-pane Irrigated or Rainfed, result is still the same using echo. Sorry for posting a common problem. I am new in array insertion to database.

```
$types = array(
    'irrigated' => 'Irrigated',
    'rainfed' => 'Rainfed',
    'upland' => 'Upland'
    );

$seed_types = array(
    'hybrid_' => 'Hybrid',
    'taggedSeeds_' => 'Tagged Seeds from (RS/FS/CS)',
    'goodSeedsTagged_' => 'Good Seeds from Tagged FS/RS',
    'goodSeedsStarter_'=>'Good Seeds from Starter RS/CS',
    'goodSeedsTraditional_'=>'Good Seeds of Traditional',
    'farmSaved_'=>'Farm Saved Seeds'
);
        foreach($types as $type){
        echo '<div id="'.$type.'" class="tab-pane fade tab-title">';
        echo "<br/>".$type."<hr/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='ecosystem' value='".$type."'>";

        foreach($seed_types as $seed_name => $seed_type){
            echo '<div class="row form-group">';
            echo '<div class="col-md-4 table-body">'.$seed_type.'</div>';
            for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {
                echo '<div class="col-md-2"><input type="number" class="form-control" name="'.$seed_name.''.$x.'" /></div>';
            }
            echo "</div>";
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }echo '<div class="row" style="border-top:dashed 1px #eaeaea;padding-top:15px;">
                <div class="col-md-11" style="text-transform:initial;">Note: Kindly check all the data before saving. Thank You.</div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input type="submit" name="save-report" value="Save Data!" class="btn btn-success">
                </div>
        </div>';

        echo '</div>';
<?php
if (isset($_POST['save-report'])) {
// Process
        global $wpdb;
        $ecosystem = $_POST['ecosystem'];
        $result = $wpdb->insert('wp_sample', array (
                                'eco_system' => "$ecosystem",
                                'type' => "$seed_type",
                                ));
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: data inserted in db is always the last value of my array.

Comment: i cannot see the submit button and `save-report` in your code

Comment: If you have multiple form fields of the same name, PHP will keep overwriting the resulting variable, and only the last entry survives. You can fix that by using a name with [] at the end, `name="foo[]"` would generate an array in $_POST['foo']. But likely that alone is not going to help you, because this would still send the values for _all_ fields of that name. You would have to dynamically disable the irrelevant fields when switching your tabs to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```
$types = array(
    'irrigated' => 'Irrigated',
    'rainfed' => 'Rainfed',
    'upland' => 'Upland'
    );

$seed_types = array(
    'hybrid_' => 'Hybrid',
    'taggedSeeds_' => 'Tagged Seeds from (RS/FS/CS)',
    'goodSeedsTagged_' => 'Good Seeds from Tagged FS/RS',
    'goodSeedsStarter_'=>'Good Seeds from Starter RS/CS',
    'goodSeedsTraditional_'=>'Good Seeds of Traditional',
    'farmSaved_'=>'Farm Saved Seeds'
);
        foreach($types as $type){
        echo '<div id="'.$type.'" class="tab-pane fade tab-title">';
        echo "<br/>".$type."<hr/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='ecosystem[]' value='".$type."'>";

        foreach($seed_types as $seed_name => $seed_type){
            echo '<div class="row form-group">';
            echo '<div class="col-md-4 table-body">'.$seed_type.'</div>';
            for ($x = 0; $x <= 3; $x++) {
                echo '<div class="col-md-2"><input type="number" class="form-control" name=[number]["'.$seed_name.''.$x.']" /></div>';
            }
            echo "</div>";
        }

        echo '</div>';
    }echo '<div class="row" style="border-top:dashed 1px #eaeaea;padding-top:15px;">
                <div class="col-md-11" style="text-transform:initial;">Note: Kindly check all the data before saving. Thank You.</div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input type="submit" name="save-report" value="Save Data!" class="btn btn-success">
                </div>
        </div>';

        echo '</div>';



<?php
    if (isset($_POST['save-report'])) {
    // Process
            global $wpdb;
            foreach($_POST['ecosystem'] as $key => $value){
                $ecosystem = $value;
                $result = $wpdb->insert('wp_sample', array (
                                        'eco_system' => $ecosystem,
                                        'type' => $seed_type,
                                        ));
            }
    }
```

Comment: it's not working,  Invalid argument supplied for foreach. currently researching to tweak code to work..